# How to remove outliers from a data array in R

Tags: r, smoothing, outliers, curvesmoothing

I would like to locate and remove the outlier in the measurement and replace with a smoothened value to capture the trend better. Please find the figure below [Data with outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzpED.png)

Comment: How are you defining "outliers." There is no universal definition. Plus good questions have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. Hopefully you've at least made some attempt at writing code yourself so share your work and describe where exactly you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You need the function `smooth`.

Example:

```
y = seq(61,68,0.5)
x = 1:15
y[7]= 59

D = data.frame(x,y)
ys = smooth(y)
Ds = data.frame(x,ys)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(D, type="b", main="Original Data")
plot(Ds, type="b", main="Smoothed Data")
```

[image: Smoothed Data]